# PHPStan starts complaining only when I am more strict about type

Tags: phpstan

I tried the following code with level 9 PHPStan:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

class Foo
{
    /** @param array<array<mixed>> $bar */
    public function foo ($bar) : void {
        if (is_array($bar)) {
            if ($bar['a']['b']['c']) return;
        }
    }
}
```

And it politely says "Cannot access offset 'c' on mixed.", which sounds right to me.

However, if I change the comment to say `/** @param array<mixed> $bar */`, instead of starting to complain about accessing 'b' and 'c' of mixed, it doesn't complain about anything. I find this behaviour unexpected, I'd expect it to be happier about my code if I provide more (correct) information about variables, but it seems to do the opposite. Why is this the case?

Also, if I remove the line `if (is_array($bar)) {`, then everything works as I'd expect, so it seems to have something to do with this, though I am not sure what and why (in any case I told it `$bar` was array, so I don't see how this should change anything)

Answer (score -1):

The answer was given [here](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/discussions/9976) by [ondrejmirtes](https://github.com/ondrejmirtes). To quote him:

> If you want all mixed types to always be reported consistently, you also need to turn on checkImplicitMixed: https://phpstan.org/config-reference#checkimplicitmixed